# Cómo ordeno un archivo de números?

Tags: c

Tuve que hacer un ejercicio sobre ordenar 2 archivos de números de forma descendente y luego guardar el contenido de ambos (ordenadamente) en un tercer archivo. Lo que hice fue transformar los 2 archivos en 2 arrays, ordenarlos y pasarlos a un tercer array para luego crear el archivo a partir de este array.
Hay alguna forma de ordenar un archivo sin tener que pasarlo a un array?
Intenté hacer esto

```
FILE *j, *k;
int aux1, aux2;

j= fopen(ejercicio5_funcion, "rb");
k= fopen("ejercicio5_listaK", "wb");
while(fread(&aux1, sizeof(int), 1, j) && fread(&aux2, sizeof(int), 1, j))
{

    if(aux1<aux2)
    {
        fwrite(&aux1, sizeof(int), 1, k);
        fseek(j, (-1)*sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR);
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite(&aux2,sizeof(int), 1, k);
        fseek(j, (-1)*sizeof(int), SEEK_CUR);

    }
}
while(!feof(j))
{
    fwrite(&aux1, sizeof(int), 1, k);
    fread(&aux1, sizeof(int), 1, j);
}
fclose(j); fclose(k);
```

Pero no tuvo resultado, solo me imprimía el valor más grande

PD: Según tengo entendido, estoy empleando el lenguaje de C para los archivos. Aclaro por las dudas

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y eso depende.. los archivos venian ordenados originalmente?

Comment: "*Hay alguna forma de ordenar un archivo sin tener que pasarlo a un array?*" Probablemente haya alguna forma de hacerlo, pero en realidad no es una buena idea. Tendrías que hacerlo todo moviéndote dentro del archivo (Y tendrias que abrirlo con `r+` para leer y escribir). Es mucho mas facil, rapido y eficiente copiarlo a un array. Porque quieres hacerlo de otro modo?

Comment: @gbianchi Ok, disculpa por las molestias! Y no, los datos fueron ingresados en los archivos de forma aleatoria

Comment: @Pablochaches era lo que pedía el ejercicio, me decía que debía ordenar los archivos para después juntarlos en otro. Estaba buscando otra forma porque no sentí que estaba correcto utilizar arrays en vez de archivos

Comment: un archivo es un array, uno esta guardado en memoria, el otro esta guardado en fisico en el disco... por una cuestion del lenguaje, es mas facil manejar arrays que archivos, pero se puede de cualquier forma...

Comment: @frobbers Bueno, lo correcto es usar arrays. Operar en los archivos es mas complicado, y mas lento